Question on generalized Heisenberg groups and unitriangular matrices
Let $F$ be a commutative field, let $V$ and $Z$ be vector spaces over $F$, and consider a symplectic bilinear map $\beta:V\times V \to Z$. We write $\langle v,w\rangle:=(v,w)^{\beta}$. Let $GH(V,Z,\beta)$ be the set $V\times Z$ endowed with the following binary operation $\circ_{\beta}$:
$$(v,y)\circ_{\beta}(w,z)=(v+w,z+\langle v,w\rangle+y).$$
The operation $\circ_{\beta}$ is associative, $(0,0)$ is a neutral element and $(-v,-z)$ is the inverse of $(v,z)$ in $GH(V,Z,\beta)$.
The group $GH(V,Z,\beta)$ is called a generalized Heisenberg group.
Now consider the group of upper unitriangular matrices $UT_3(F)$ of dimension 3 over $F$ with matrix multiplication.
$$UT_3(F)=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\colon a,b,c\in F\right\}$$
My question is: Is there a way of fitting $UT_3(F)$ into the definition of generalized Heisenberg group?
I tried setting $G:=UT_3(F)$, $V=G/Z(G)$, $Z=Z(G)$ and the map $\beta:V\times V \to Z$ defined by $\langle v,w\rangle=[v,w]=v^{-1}w^{-1}vw$. But I wasn't able to construct an isomorphism between $UT_3(F)$ and $GH(G/Z(G),Z(G),\beta)$.

You need characteristic different from $2$, as $UT_3(F)$ is never abelian, but $GH(V,Z,\beta)$ is, since $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle$.

Assume characteristic different from 2. I am more interested in the case where the characteristic is 0.
